# Executar uma ação quando um botão é clicado pela primeira vez e outra caso contrário

Tags: java, swing, jbutton

Gostaria de saber como fazer um if quando o botão é clicado.
Por exemplo:

```
private void btnEditarActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                          


    ProdutosDAO produtoDAO = new ProdutosDAO(); 


    if(btnCaminhoImagem.isSelected()){
     conexaoProdutos.conexao();
    modeloProdutos.setPrecoUnitario(pegarDouble());
    modeloProdutos.setNacionalidade(jtfNacionalidade.getText());
    modeloProdutos.setTipo(jtfTipo.getText());
    modeloProdutos.setQuantidadeEstoque(Integer.valueOf(jtfQuantidadeEstoque.getText()));
    modeloProdutos.setProduto(jtfProduto.getText());
    modeloProdutos.setCaracteristicas(jtfCaracteristicas.getText());
    modeloProdutos.setStatusAtivoInativo(setaRadioButtonGeneroSexo());
    modeloProdutos.setImagem(fis);
    modeloProdutos.setEmbalagem(String.valueOf(jcbEmbalagem.getSelectedItem()));
    modeloProdutos.setTamanhoMl(jtfTamanhoMl.getText());

    produtoDAO.editarProdutosTrocaImagem(modeloProdutos);
    limparCampos();
    }else{
       conexaoProdutos.conexao();  
              modeloProdutos.setPrecoUnitario(pegarDouble());
    modeloProdutos.setNacionalidade(jtfNacionalidade.getText());
    modeloProdutos.setTipo(jtfTipo.getText());
    modeloProdutos.setQuantidadeEstoque(Integer.valueOf(jtfQuantidadeEstoque.getText()));
    modeloProdutos.setProduto(jtfProduto.getText());
    modeloProdutos.setCaracteristicas(jtfCaracteristicas.getText());
    modeloProdutos.setStatusAtivoInativo(setaRadioButtonGeneroSexo());
    modeloProdutos.setEmbalagem(String.valueOf(jcbEmbalagem.getSelectedItem()));
    modeloProdutos.setTamanhoMl(jtfTamanhoMl.getText());

    produtoDAO.editarProdutos(modeloProdutos);
    limparCampos();


    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

Para efetuar uma ação quando o botão for clicado, basta adicionar um listener, conforme abaixo:

```
seuJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    // sua ação aqui
  } 
});
```

---

## UPDATE

Se quiser controlar se o botão já foi clicado anteriormente ao menos uma vez, você pode criar uma variável booleana como um "sinalizador" de que já entrou no evento:

```
boolean buttonHasClicked = false;
```

Depois, cheque no método se foi clicado, e altere o status da variavel:

```
seuJButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() { 
  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) { 
    if(!buttonHasClicked){
       //ação se já não foi clicado
       buttonHasclicked = true;
    }else{
       //ação se já foi clicado antes
    }
  } 
});
```

Seria bom da uma lida na [documentação oficial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html), tem muitos exemplos lá demonstrando mais sobre componentes.

Comment: Não, na verdade s[o preciso verificar se o botão foi clicado... simples assim..

Comment: @CarlosLeandroFerreiradeAlm olha se é isso que você queria fazer.

Comment: Pode usar [JToggleButton](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JToggleButton.html).

Comment: @renan pensei nessa opção, mas segundo o que ele disse nos comentários(que ainda está meio obscuro), ele quer checar se o botão foi clicado na ação de clique de outro botão.

Comment: @CarlosLeandroFerreiradeAlm caso a solução tenha lhe ajudado, você pode marcar como aceita, clicando no `v` a esquerda, assim, servirá de referencia para outras pessoas com problema semelhate :)